# Filling in a shape python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

so I made a snowflake script and I wanna fill each yellow with yellow and each blue with blue.
Here is the code if anyone can help, thank you!

```
screen=turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
import random
elsa = turtle.Turtle()
colours = ["yellow","blue",]
elsa.color("yellow")
for i in range(20):
    for i in range(2):
        elsa.fd(100)
        elsa.right(60)
        elsa.fd(100)
        elsa.right(120)
    elsa.right(36)
    fillcolor("blue")
    elsa.color(random.choice(colours))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already set the fill color to match the pen color when you called `color()`, you need only add the `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` calls:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

colours = ["yellow", "blue",]

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

elsa = Turtle()
elsa.color("yellow")

for i in range(10):
    elsa.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        elsa.forward(100)
        elsa.right(60)
        elsa.forward(100)
        elsa.right(120)

    elsa.end_fill()

    elsa.right(36)
    elsa.color(choice(colours))

elsa.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```